# Element type is invalid expected a string undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am following a course on React Native that seems to be a little out of date.
Just trying to import a single component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import TaskList from './TaskList';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {
        todos:[
          {
            task:'Learn React Native'
          },
        ],
      };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TaskList />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

**TaskList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const {
    Text,
} = React;

class TaskList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hi this is the TaskList!</Text>
    );
  }
}

export default TaskList;
```

I have looked around and I am not doing wrong what others where

Comment: in `TaskList` try to do `import {  Text } from 'react-native'` , instead of `const { Text, } = React;`

Comment: Solved it, do you want to post your fix, THANK YOU

Comment: cool, glad it works for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Text` should be imported from `react-native`. In `TaskList` try to do

```
 import { 
   Text, 
 } from 'react-native'
```

instead of

```
 const {
   Text,
 } = React;
```

Comment: this was huge for me. took me hours to notice. thank you @Cherniv